# TexMaker pdf view keeps jumping. How to stop it from doing that?

Tags: texmaker

I have a main file and I input many other files into this one. When I compile the main file while editing one of the input-files, the pdf view jumps to a random location or to the location of the cursor in the main file.

I want the pdf view to be fixed. Is there a way of doing that? Is there a way to de-sync the cursor in the main file and the pdf viewer?

Comment: Or if you edit a single file and this file is a Beamer, this auto-jump is a nightmare too.

Comment: I'm not sure, but have you tried using an external viewer instead of the built in one?

Answer (score 0):

The Toggle for synchronising the PDF viewer and editor is Usually Ctrl +Space

To check what it is currently set at go to  Options Configure Shortcuts
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that was not really what I was looking for. This Ctrl+Space helps me move from the editor to the corresponding location in the pdf. But what I need is: when I click on the view pdf button or quick build, the pdf should not synchronize with the cursor in the editor. The pdf should stay in the same location.